# R Windows OS choose.dir() File chooser won't open at working directory

Tags: r, filechooser, working-directory

The choose.dir function reference page there is an example:

```
choose.dir(getwd(), "Choose a suitable folder")
```

Which should start the folder choice window at the working directory. However I am only having the folder choice window open at 'My Computer'. What reasons could there be for this function not working as intended?

Comment: What OS and R version? What does `getwd()` return?

Comment: I should have mentioned that getwd() does not return "My Computer", it gives the path to my working directory. I'm using RStudio  0.99.485 , with R version 3.2.0 on Windows mingw32. getwd() is in the in {utils} package, I'm not sure if that is specific to Windows. What is the result others get when using the example code?

Comment: Maybe. I took that to mean that you can't select folder with a path this outside 'Computer', rather than stating that the default location for choose.dir() has to be 'Computer' on Windows.  Does 'choose.dir(getwd())' work for others, or is it only not working for me?

Comment: `choose.dir()` only exists on Windows, so I can't check ... *is* your working directory outside `Computer`, i.e. on a different drive (I guess)?

Comment: ' getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/bla35s/Documents"' and C: is inside 'Computer'

Comment: I guess the solution would be to not use choose.dir(), as relying on it would preclude usage by other OS anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right in that you should not use `choose.dir()`, as it is OS-specific. I can indeed reproduce the issue you report - my guess is that it won't let you start in a directory that belongs to the "Root" user (whatever that may mean in Windows), because it seems to work well for other directories, not under 'Root':

```
 getwd()
 # [1] "C:/Users/Root/Documents"
 choose.dir(getwd(), "Choose a suitable folder") # leads to 'Computer'

 setwd("C:/datathon")
 choose.dir(getwd(), "Choose a suitable folder") # select subfolder 'scripts', works OK
 # [1] "C:\\datathon\\scripts"
```

There are two OS-independent solutions; the first, as it has been [pointed out](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-August/077390.html) before, is to use the following functionality from the `tcltk` package:

```
 library(tcltk)
 setwd('~')
 getwd()
 # [1] "C:/Users/Root/Documents"
 dir <- tclvalue(tkchooseDirectory())  # opens a dialog window in 'My Documents'
```

The second is to use the `rChoiceDialogs` package (requires `rJava`):

```
 library(rJava)
 library(rChoiceDialogs)
 getwd()
 # [1] "C:/Users/Root/Documents"
 jchoose.dir()  # opens the dialog window in "C:\\Users\\Root\\Documents"
```