# Mac fail to setwd:error in cannot change in working directory

Tags: r

I was trying to change my working directory from the default one in R. I tried both

> setwd('~/Users/Weindependent/Desktop/GSE/EDU 767/Assignment')
>   and
>   setwd('Users/Weindependent/Desktop/GSE/EDU 767/Assignment')

but still get the error

> Error in setwd("/Users/Weindependent/Desktop/GSE/EDU 767/Assignment") : 
>     cannot change working directory

I also tried to define

> workdirec <- "/Users/Weindependent/Desktop/GSE/EDU 767/Assignment"
>   setwd(workdirec)

but still get the same error

What is the problem?

Comment: If you're working with Rstudio try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692296/having-trouble-setting-working-directory

Comment: Also, double check your path to make sure it actually exits, and you don't have a typo in it.

Comment: In addition to @Mako212 . Try using     getwd() to find the path you are currently using, copy, paste and modify it into     setwd()

Comment: You can always use `choose.dir()` to verify the path too