# R Studio: working directory does not change despite using setwd and not getting an error message

Tags: r

I want to change the working directory and using setwd I don't get any error message. Yet the working directory doesn't change. Could someone help me out?

My code and output:

```
> setwd("/Users/username/Desktop/Replication/Data")
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/username"
```

Comment: You need to give more context.  How did you run those lines?  Were you using R in the console, in RStudio, or what?  Have the `setwd` or `getwd` functions been modified? They should both be calls to `.Internal()` in `base`.

Comment: see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692296/having-trouble-setting-working-directory