# is it impossible to update “utils” package?

Tags: r, package

I am with MRO 3.5.3 on Ubintu 18.04, when using utils::choose.dir, it says "no such function". But it is there at R document site. After checking, the `utils` library is 3.5.3, and the latest is 3.6.1.

> `> installPackages("utils")
>
> Installing package into ‘/home/kkk/R/x86_64-pc-
>   linux-gnu-library/3.5’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified)
>
> Warning messages:
>
> 1: package ‘utils’ is not available
>   (for R version 3.5.3)
>   2: package ‘utils’ is a base package, and
>   should not be updated

How can I update the `utils` and get the function I need?
Thanks

Comment: I think you need to update the R version and `utils` library will be auto-updated.

Comment: I thought Microsoft R open (MRO) 3.5.3 is already the latest. Thanks.

Comment: `utils`, along with many other "base packages", are only updated with the entire R installation. They are not available as individual packages. While there may be other reasons, the biggest rationale I can think of for this is that so much of R's internal workings rely on tight coupling between these packages, and changing much of the ABI/API could endanger that. Weak, perhaps, but ... still, you can't update these packages, just update R.

Comment: As for why you cannot find that function: [`?choose.dir`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/choose.dir.html) states that *"This is only available on Windows."*.

Comment: How stupid I am! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the {rstudioapi} is the solution for specific function.

[OS-independent way to select directory interactively in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218491/os-independent-way-to-select-directory-interactively-in-r)

Comment: Side note, though, is that this does not work unless actually using RStudio. For most this won't be a problem, but any other IDE is still out of luck.