# Unable to change default directory in R utils::choose.dir()

Tags: r

I'm using utils::choose.dir() and choose.files() to select and save files. I can set the opening directory in choose.files() using a fully-qualified path name, but choose.dir always opens at the default "", even when I run the example in the help file:

```
        choose.dir(getwd(), "Choose a suitable folder")
```

It still opens at This PC. I have tried `dirname(dataName)` as the first argument and also a character string with a fully-qualified path name and there is no difference.

How can I make this happen?

I'm running Windows 10 Home version 1903 and R 4.0.2

This question is similar to [R Windows OS choose.dir() File chooser won't open at working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511964/r-windows-os-choose-dir-file-chooser-wont-open-at-working-directory), but that one focused on MacOS. I'm hoping to get this to work as stated in the documentation example on Windows.

I'm okay with moving to tcltk (which does do what I need), but I'm trying to understand if the problem as stated is on my end.

Thanks

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33511964/3358272

Comment: I was hoping to get choose.dir() to work as in the example and keep everything in the utils package, but tk_choose.dir() does what I need. Am I correct in thinking that a separate intall of tk/tcl is not required? I have numerous supporting programs on my machine that some others may not have, so I don't know if I'm picking that up by default.

Comment: R includes `tcltk` (whether you want it or not), which should give you most (all?) of what you need. (I don't know for sure, frankly, I don't use it.)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I changed to tcltk and works. It seems several people have raised similar questions but there doesn't seem to be a usable response on using utils::choose.dir(). I'd be happy with something saying the package example doesn't work, but maybe I'm still missing something. I'll go with tcltk unless I can find something better.